# Access violation 1064 error while migrating pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am getting these errors while creating a pivot table and migrating it.
This is my code for pivot table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class HotelUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hotel_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('hotel_id')->refrences('id')->on('hotels');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->refrences('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hotel_user');
    }
}
```

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>      corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `hotel
>     _user` add constraint `hotel_user_hotel_id_foreign` foreign key (`hotel_id`) references `hotels` ())

In Connection.php line 452:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>      corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: images of code do not help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and more specifically the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. I've corrected this post, and fixed some of the common mistakes, but on future posts reading this article would go a long way to making high quality posts for future visitors.

Comment: see my answer. its typo references

Answer (score 0):

check the spelling of references

change **refrences** to **references**